# Errno 2. No such file or directory. Beautiful soup link with changeable variable

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, errno

I try to pull data from a website with several pages. 
My idea is to use a loop that uses the number of available pages.

So I use a link with a variable for this purpose. 
But it doesn't work with bs4 and I can't understand why.
The same link works for method "driver.get" but for "beautiful soup" the error [Errno 2] shows up.

```
#First time data upload from the site
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.site.ca/dried")
doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
results = doc.find("div", {"class": "row js-equalize"})
links = results.findAll("a")

#Calculation of the total amount of available pages and creation of a loop
for lis in results.find_all('ul', attrs={"class" : "pull-right pagination"}):
    p = lis.text.replace("Page ","")
    p = re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', p)
    for i in range(len(p)):
        j=i+1
        driver.get("https://www.site.ca/dried-?page="+str(j))
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500000)

        list_of_sku = []

        soup = BeautifulSoup(open('https://www.site.ca/dried-?page='+str(j)), "html.parser")
```

Here is the error I got.
When I click on the link below it works well. (the site name was changed for privacy purpose)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('https://www.site.ca/dried-?page='+str(j)), "html.parser")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://www.site.ca/dried-?page=1'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone explain to me how to avoid this issue?

Comment: First time you create a BeautifulSoup instance you pass it the content of the web page from selenium... WHY would you try to to **open a file** instead of doing exactly the same the second time you do this, inside the loop??? Remove the `open('https://www.site.ca/dried-?page='+str(j))` and put `driver.page_source` there.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I used "open" there. I spent 2 hours looking for a mistake in the code.